# regu tools matlab l_curve

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve one of the famous stanford EE263 problems, which gives me matrix A representing blurring of an image and y, representing the blurred image. For that I have been trying to use Peter Hansen regu tools package, and specifically the l-curve algorithm he provides. The problem is that after computer the singular value decomposition the program gets stuck in a line.
This is my code:

```
 [U,S,V]=svds(A);

 [reg_corner,rho,eta,reg_param] = l_curve(U,S,y);
```

I use svds because A is given to me in sparse format. S is the diagonal matrix containing the first 6 singular values. The error I get is this one:

```
  Error using  ./ 
  Matrix dimensions must agree.

  Error in l_corner (line 64)
  xi = beta./s;
```

and  l_corner.m defines beta like this:

```
    if (nargin > 3)
        [p,ps] = size(s); [m,n] = size(U);
        beta = U'*b;
        if (m>n), b0 = b - U*beta; end
    if (ps==2)
        s = s(p:-1:1,1)./s(p:-1:1,2);
        beta = beta(p:-1:1);
    end
    xi = beta./s;
    end
```

so beta is a 6x1 matrix, and cannot be ./ divided by s which is 6x6. 
Just to clarify I am a masters in engineering student (no mathematician) and I am taking an applied liner algebra course, for which the professor uses the stanford material. Any insight into how to use the regu tools package will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

s has to be a vector of singular values, not a diagonal matrix S from the SVD. For this you can use [U,s,V] = csvd(A); from the same regularization toolbox.